# HQL transformation

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am a newbie with HQL and I am trying to do this :

```
select count(T) from (
    select inscription, max(wrd_step) as max 
    from table aa 
    where rd_context = ? 
    group by inscription
) as T
where T.max = ?
```

The error is :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 21 [select count(T) from( select inscription, max(wrd_step) from table aa where rd_context = ? group by inscription) as T where T.max = ?]
```

Thanks

EDIT :

The query in HQL is :

```
SELECT count(distinct inscription)
FROM Entity
WHERE inscription in (
    select distinct inscription
    from Entity 
    where rd_context = ?
    group by inscription
    having max(wrd_step) = ?
)
```

Comment: select count(T.inscription) form (...) as T where T.max = ?

Comment: To start with in HQL you shouldn't query against tables, instead you use entities and paths between associations. This affects the way you structure your queries. Start by reading [Chapter 16 - HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html) of the [Hibernate Core Reference Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/). If you can't find a way to translate your original query, as a last resort you can fall back to [Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html) and or mapping entities to database views.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the "table" is in fact an entity. But thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate documentation states:

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries

But assuming `table` is a mapped entity (*is it?*), you can do this (not tested):

```
select count(aa)
from table aa 
where rd_context = :param1 
group by inscription
having max(wrd_step) = :param2
```

Comment: Thanks that's really help me a lot !

Your query needed a little transformation to be good. The exact query is in my first post, see edit.